# make jquery tab using ngRoute angularjs doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to add item in tab 1, then navigate to the next tab, when I come back, things will got reset.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ETxaZ2ESI9ftCOUSRDcP?p=preview

what is the best approach to build jquery tab using angular? ngshow and hide is not that friendly as it makes the view complicated and messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [Bootstrap components](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) written by the AngularUI Team. you can find a great set of Twitter Bootstrap components including Tabs control.

**example:**

```
<div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
  <p>Select a tab by setting active binding to true:</p>
  <p>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="tabs[0].active = true">Select second tab</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="tabs[1].active = true">Select third tab</button>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="tabs[1].disabled = ! tabs[1].disabled">Enable / Disable third tab</button>
  </p>
  <hr />

  <tabset>
    <tab heading="Static title">Static content</tab>
    <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
      {{tab.content}}
    </tab>
    <tab select="alertMe()">
      <tab-heading>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i> Alert!
      </tab-heading>
      I've got an HTML heading, and a select callback. Pretty cool!
    </tab>
  </tabset>

  <hr />

  <tabset vertical="true" type="navType">
    <tab heading="Vertical 1">Vertical content 1</tab>
    <tab heading="Vertical 2">Vertical content 2</tab>
  </tabset>

  <hr />

  <tabset justified="true">
    <tab heading="Justified">Justified content</tab>
    <tab heading="SJ">Short Labeled Justified content</tab>
    <tab heading="Long Justified">Long Labeled Justified content</tab>
  </tabset>
</div>
```

js:

```
var TabsDemoCtrl = function ($scope) {
  $scope.tabs = [
    { title:"Dynamic Title 1", content:"Dynamic content 1" },
    { title:"Dynamic Title 2", content:"Dynamic content 2", disabled: true }
  ];

  $scope.alertMe = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert("You've selected the alert tab!");
    });
  };

  $scope.navType = 'pills';
};
```

Live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/ExDYMWfK0FKgk0IDw47q?p=preview